# $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{M(t)}{t}dt=o(x)$ implies $M(x)=o(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Show that $$\int_{1-}^{x}\frac{M(t)}{t}dt=o(x)$$ implies $$M(x)=o(x)$$
where $M(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)$. My idea is complicated and goes like this : Note that $$\frac{M(t)}{t}dt=dM*t^{-1}dt$$
Now multiplying an 'approximate inverse' for $t^{-1}dt$ in the above equation and then integrating and using the hypothesis , we get $$\frac{M(x)}{x}+\frac{\int_{1}^{x}M(t)dt}{x^2}=o(1) $$ Using this equation recurrently one can get the desired result. The 'approximate inverse' i used was $d\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$. I think this is not the intended solution. This a exercise from Bateman and Diamond's text on Analytic number thoery.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true without further hypotheses on $M(x)$.

Comment: Don't we love those nice little exercises? The conclusion ($M(x)=o(x)$) is equivalent to the Prime Number Theorem, btw. But then, the hypothesis is far from trivial, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true in general, you need to use that $|M(x+n)-M(x)| \le n$.

Assume that $|M(x_k)| > a x_k$ for infinitely many $k$, and find a contradiction from  $$\int_{x_k-a x_k}^{x_k}  \frac{M(t)}{t}dt = \int_1^{x_k} \frac{M(t)}{t}dt- \int_1^{x_k-a x_k} \frac{M(t)}{t}dt=o(x_k)$$

Comment: Using your idea , this should be true in general : If $R(x)$ is increasing and non-negetive then $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{R(t)}{t}dt=cx+o(x)$ if and only if $R(x)=cx+o(x)$

Comment: @user244821 If $R$ is increasing this is trivial. The Mertens function $M(x)$ is everything but increasing..